How do I get rid of a phantom USB device in Linux?
For the last few months there has been a constant flow of messages of the following form in dmesg:
[   93.631038] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
[   93.631184] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[   93.838652] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[   94.050219] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 124, error -71
[   94.050257] usb 1-8: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[   94.167084] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 125 using xhci_hcd
[   94.167189] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[   94.375534] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[   94.586723] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 125, error -71
[   94.586830] usb 1-8: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[   94.586919] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device
[   94.894226] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 126 using xhci_hcd
[   95.010984] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   95.230185] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   95.450261] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd
[   95.565799] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   95.791642] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   95.901208] usb usb1-port8: attempt power cycle

But there is no such device 1-8:
$ echo -n '1-8' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
1-8tee: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind: No such device

The messages do not correspond to anything I have plugged in:
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c34b Logitech, Inc. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:706e Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

lsusb -t
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 113, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 113, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 004: Dev 114, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 006: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 006: Dev 004, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 007: Dev 005, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M

At the same time, lsusb now takes about 11 seconds to run and newly connected USB device take about that long to be recognized. Certain USB device, such as my scanner, are recognized but my computer can no longer communicate with them.
So somehow the kernel is seeing a phantom device and this appears to be interfering with the rest of the USB subsystem.
I have tried forcing USB 2.0 and disabling USB power management in the kernel options to no avail. I have looked into the BIOS/UEFI setup tool but was unable to find anything to identify and disable this port.
I'm running 6.8.0-44-generic on Ubuntu 24.04.
Does this indicate a hardware defect? How do I get rid of this?

What shows up if you lsusb -t  ? Is this a laptop or desktop?

The comment field won't let me paste that output, so I added it to the question above.
It's a laptop.

This flood of messages likely indicates that you have something on one of your USB ports that is pulling D+ high, which indicates "connect event". But there is nothing else behind this port, so the very first "Set_Address" fails. Since the basic response fails, the system cannot get_descriptor, so it does not know what it is, and lsusb shows nothing. Since the D+=HIGH condition likely persists, the system makes continuous attempts of "reset-enumerate" trying increasing address and cycling over.
The dummy D+=high condition could be because of a faulty ESD protection circuit on one of the ports. Or conductive dirt on the board. I also have seen some idiot manufacturers of USB LED lamp where D+ was pulled high but no USB functionality.
Technically the host should stop dealing with faulty port if the condition persists, but it looks like the fault in your case is intermittent, and that's why the timeout does not work.
